# Integrating GooglePay with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-pay

so I have a task of integrating GooglePay into our react app...

The general approach suggested in the documentation:

```
        const button = this.paymentsClient.createButton({
            onClick: () => console.log('TODO: click handler')
        });
        document
            .getElementsByClassName('my-payment-class')[0]
            .appendChild(button);
```

Works perfectly however this is not a very 'react' way of doing things...

The button returns this: 
[image]

So my idea was to render it using:

```
            return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: button }} />;
```

However this renders to:

[image]

When I try to render it in jsx

```
return <div > {button} </div>;
```

it throws a Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]).

Anyone has a working implementation to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the API returns a DOM element, not a React element. That's why React can't render it

As you well pointed, you can use `appendChild` on the React element, or the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property in its JSX representation. Note though that when you take the latter approach, the React element is expecting the raw HTML of the DOM element, not the object itself. You can access the raw HTML content of the DOM using the `innerHTML` property, like so:

`return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: button.innerHTML }} />;`